# Make a Google Calendar readable/writable out from a specific website

Tags: google-calendar-api

I've a Google Calendar into my Google account and an API key created on console.cloud.google.
I don't want to make the calendar public but at the same time, i need to read and insert new events from a website of mine.

Actually i made all works but only setting the calendar as public, but this implies that everyone, from any source knowing the calendar ID can read it! And that causes a "little" problem with privacy..

So, how i can make it work limiting the read and write operations to my website?

Comment: What is your goal here?

Comment: I've a Bed and Breakfast and and i need to manage clients appointments. So, from my website i need to read actual appointments and show to the user only the avaible dates.
Meanwhile on my google account i've create a calendar named  "BaB" 
Once the user  selected a date, filled personal details (name, telephone etc..) and submit it (throught the website), i will save this details into the my "BaB" calendar.

Obviously i don't want to make the "BaB" calendar public for preserve privacy. The only source that can perform read/write operation on the calendar should be my website.

Comment: Can you share how do you have it now, what call are you making or how you have it setup?